# Evaluating Azure Devops Expressions within Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I want to be able to invoke the [Counter expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) within a template but I am unsure how to do so; my current template yml file looks like this:

```
parameters:
- name: major 
  type: string
  default: '1'
- name: minor 
  type: string
  default: '0'

steps: 

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set NuGet package version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $isMain = ('$(Build.SourceBranch)' -eq 'refs/heads/main')

      $minor = ${{ parameters.minor }}
      $revision1 = $[counter($minor, 1)] 
      Write-Host $revision
      exit 0
```

But I get:

> The term '$[counter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I am guessing there is way I can invoke the function via Powershell.

The reason for me wanting to do this in the template as opposed to passing it in as a parameter from the consumer of the template is because seemingly parameters are not evaluated when passed into a template.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this within a powershell script? I'm not seeing anything that you can't do with YAML conditions. Also, please explain what you mean by *seemingly parameters are not evaluated when passed into a template.*. Do you understand the distinction between template compile-time expressions (`${{}}`), runtime expressions (`$[]`), and macro expressions? (`$()`)?

Comment: The *specific* error you're getting is because `$[]` is a **runtime** expression. The powershell script you're trying to run is getting finalized during **compile** time. This line: `$revision1 = $[counter($minor, 1)]` **cannot possibly** work. You are trying to take the results of a powershell script expression and use it in a YAML function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Evaluating Azure Devops Expressions within Powershell

Just as Daniel said that:

> The powershell script you're trying to run is getting finalized
> during compile time. This line: $revision1 = $[counter($minor, 1)]
> cannot possibly work. You are trying to take the results of a
> powershell script expression and use it in a YAML function.

That is reason why it is not work for you.

And personally think you can go the easier way, just define the variable in the **main** YAML file：

`azure-pipelines.yml`：

```
variables:
  - name: minor
    value: 0
  - name: revision1
    value: $[counter(variables['minor'], 0)]


stages:
- stage: Run
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - template: Template.yml
```

And we could use the the Counter in the template directly:

`Template.yml`:

```
steps: 
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set NuGet package version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host '$(revision1)'
```

The test result:

[image]